# How to group rows based on it's ordering and limiting rows count in group?

Tags: mysql, group-by

Sample data:

```
id type 
1  0
2  1
3  0
4  1
5  0
6  1
7  0
10 1
11 1
12 1
13 1
15 1
```

Expected result after grouping, if max rows count in group is 3, and we can merge rows with same type in range 2 rows after current:

```
id type count ids(no need to output it, it's only for understanding)
1  0    3     1,3,5
2  1    3     2,4,6
7  0    1     7
10 1    3     10,11,12
15 1    1     15
```

Merging adjacent rows is simple done by using variables, but merging rows with same type through another it's hell.
How i can do it in MySQL, or this isn't possible?

Comment: Can I clarify, you want the first `id`, grouped by `type` and you want a maximum group size of 3?

Comment: Partial yes. But i want group based on row position, if two rows adjacent, and have same type - UNION, or if range current row position - 2 to current row position has element with same type and groups count <= 3 - union with it(or simply not select because we already have min(id))

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already figured out how to use variables, I am showing only '...':

```
( SELECT min(id) AS mid_id, type, ...
    FROM tbl
    WHERE type = 0
    ORDER BY id
)
UNION ALL
( SELECT min(id) AS mid_id, type, ...
    FROM tbl
    WHERE type = 1
    ORDER BY id
)
ORDER BY mid_id;
```

That should work for a small, fixed, number of types.  Else, you need an extra variable, plus rearrange the data before processing it; then rearrange again afterwards:

```
SELECT  ... -- break on changes in `type` in addition to every 3rd item
    FROM (
        SELECT * FROM tbl
            ORDER BY type, id -- first rearrangement
         )
    ORDER BY min_id  -- second rearrangement
```